# The page isn't redirecting properly to Site Maintenance page

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, global-asax

I want to allow certain users from specific IP address to work on the web application and others will see only the Site under maintenance page.

My code is as follows written in Global.asax

```
    void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Site under Maintainance Code
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"]))
            {
                if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedIPs"] != null)
                {
                    string[] allowedIPs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedIPs"].ToString().Split(';');
                    if (!allowedIPs.Contains(GetIP()))
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/Common/PageUnderConstruction.aspx", false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private string GetIP()
    {
        string strHostName = "";
        strHostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

        IPHostEntry ipEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);

        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        return addr[addr.Length - 1].ToString();

    }
```

The initial page is Login.aspx, during this PageUnderConstruction page redirection is done properly, after that it goes into loop as Global.asax beginrequest method is executed again and finally I get the "The page isn't redirecting properly" error.

Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: Do you really want to rewrite the path or did you mean to use `Response.Redirect()`?

Comment: Did you only do the redirection if the requested URL does not end in "PageUnderConstruction.aspx"?

Comment: Yes. I have also tried that. but No luck.